# Interchange of limit and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

After reading "limit interchange operations" from Wikipedia, I have a question regarding interchange of limit with supremum. Under what conditions we can make the following interchange:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq 0} f(m,n)= \sup_{m \geq 0}\lim_{n \to \infty}f(m,n)$$
One can assume f(m,n) is nonnegative.

Comment: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(m,n)$ exists uniformly w.r.t. $m$ then you can interchange.

Comment: Sir can you please prove it